# MySQL table creation GUI with good keyboard shortcuts? Windows or Web-based

Tags: mysql, database-design

This seems like a trivial thing, but one of the biggest slowdowns in my workflow has become logging in to phpmyadmin for creating and modifying tables- my biggest gripe is the complete lack of keyboard support. I just need a simple tool to generate (and run, ideally) create table and alter statements.

Edit: after thinking on this a bit, something that was a web-based spreadsheet for me to type into (think Google Docs) with columns for colName, colType, colLength (where applicable) that generated a create table statement would suffice. Does this exist or am I about to code something to use Google Docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend **SQLyog** but there is a more "professional" tool: **navicat lite for mySQL** (it has versions for other SQL too like Oracle) or **SQL-Front**

Comment: I've tried Navicat some time ago, along with MySQL Workbench, neither seemed to have a good keyboard interface. (i.e. I'd like to be able to alt-tab in, and create a table and such without using the mouse)

I'll check out SQL-Front.